# SQL Server 2008 Jobs Steps

Tags: sql-server-2008, jobs

Hi i have a Job in SQL Server with the below steps . I wanted to know what code is getting executed when this Job get executed

Steps Details :

Database : master 
Command : --Added by Application Program Interface or API

How i can locate the code that is getting executed . Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In SSMS, find the SQL Agent Job, right-click it, and "Script Job as" ... "CREATE To" a new window.  That should give you some clues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer new query editor window it is making some entries in the MSDB database jobs related table .Since in the command it is written "--Added by Application Program Interface or API". i don't understand what code is getting executed behind. –  Vishal Srivastav

Answer (score 0):

If you know the job name which is getting executed. You can get the code by --->

```
Object Explorer --> SQL Server Agent --> Jobs --> (Right click on your job name) --> Script job as --> Create to --> new query editor window
```

you will get the complete code of you job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer new query editor window it is making some entries in the MSDB database jobs related table .Since in the command it is  written "--Added by Application Program Interface or API". i don't understand what code is getting executed behind.